# Console pops up by hovering over method, Eclipse Neon on Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, console, popup, eclipse-neon

I have updated my Eclipse version from Kepler to Neon. In general I work with two screens. The main one shows code, hierarchies,... and the second one shows a window with 2 console tabs in it.

With Kepler there wasn't any problem but now with Neon when I hover over a method, constructor or something else which leads to open up a description, the window switches automatically from the second screen to the main one.

Does someone of you has an idea to avoid this "pop-up"-behaviour? I would really appreciate an answer :)

Kindly regards
Lukas

Comment: This really isn't a coding question.

Comment: @screenmutt: It is about programming tools, though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a whole new window (Window -> New Window) instead of moving the detached window to the other screen.

Note that the detached console window is not the same kind as the window you are creating with Window -> New Window. The detached window is a sub-window and belongs to a main window (featured with command bar at the top). If this sub-window was at the other monitor, it jumps back. Now the created "main window with the command bar" doesn't do this jump.

Hopefully it helps.